# Ignoring characters in the input

Tags: c++, input

Input:

> 3
>
> 23 + 47 = machula
>
> 3247 + 5machula2 = 3749
>
> machula13 + 75425 = 77038

I was solving a question in spoj where the input was in the form "string +  string = string". I had to store the first, second and the third numbers in strings skipping the '+' and '='. For that I created two char variables to store the '+' and '='.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int iii = 0; iii < t; iii += 1)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        int num1, num2, num3;
        int condition = 0;
        string input1;
        cin >> input1;
        if (input1.find("machula") != string::npos)
        {
            condition = 1;
        }
        char op1;
        cin >> op1;
        string input2;
        cin >> input2;
        if (input2.find("machula") != string::npos)
        {
            condition = 2;
        }
        char op2;
        cin >> op2;
        string input3;
        cin >> input3;
        if (input3.find("machula") != string::npos)
        {
            condition = 3;
        }
        switch (condition)
        {
            case 1:
                num2 = stoi(input2);
                num3 = stoi(input3);
                num1 = num3 - num2;
                break;
            case 2:
                num1 = stoi(input1);
                num3 = stoi(input3);
                num2 = num3 - num1;
                break;
            case 3:
                num1 = stoi(input1);
                num2 = stoi(input2);
                num3 = num1 + num2;
                break;
        }
        cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num3 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to ignore the '+' and the '=' in the input along with the whitespaces?

Comment: Use a [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is always in the form of

```
<str1> <op> <str2> = <str3>
```

You can read all tokens and do nothing with the op and =, for example:

```
std::string s1 op s2 eq s3;

std::cin >> s1 >> op >> s2 >> eq >> s3;
```

You can validate that op and eq are what you expect, or can ignore them altogether.  The standard behaviour of istream will skip whitespaces on its own, so you don't have to worry about that.